# Detailed URL fetch info in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

Is there any way I could get info such as how long did it take to connect to a remote server, time taken to receive the first byte of response, and the time taken to download the whole file?

I'm trying to create something like what [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) does.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pingdom.com](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/_img/img_explanation.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with sockets, like this:

```
require "socket"

# START MEASURING CONNECTION TIME
connection = TCPSocket.open("example.com", 80)
# END MEASURING CONNECTION TIME

connection.print "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n"

# START MEASURING RESPONSE FETCHING TIME
response = connection.read
# END MEASURING RESPONSE FETCHING TIME

connection.close
```